# Google Photos really doesn't care for folder hierarchy on backups?

Tags: backup, google-drive, google-photos

I've enabled the auto-backup feature from Google Photos on my Android phone, and every here and there it asked me through notifications if I wanted to backup a new given folder.
I keep my photos organized on my device through a couple of folders, such as "Parties", "Work events", "games", and so on.

Well done, some of those folders were gone from my phone, not sure why. That's a task for the backup feature, right?
**Wrong, it seems!** I can't seem to find the given folders in my Google Photos. Am I mistaken or the backup feature selects folders but ends up placing *all pictures in the same basket*, only organizing by date?? It should backup folders as well, not only the files inside them, getting rid of the hierarchy! How stupid could that be??

**Is it possible to enable folder backup *with* their current hierarchy?**

Furthermore, there are some very old pictures (2008/2009) which are showing up as 2022/2023, clogging up my "recents" view. How do I fix that?

Comment: I have the same issue. They seem to suggest making a feature request to Google Photos developers ! https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/photos/unYhvcUfGyI